# how to use remember me in gocart (CI)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, remember-me

I want to use remember me but it's not working.I am using login function as

```
$this->Customer_model->login($email, $password, $remember);
```

where `$remember = true;`

but when I close my browser it makes me logout.

Comment: You can use the `session` to record

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session to record

```
$data = array('remember' => TRUE);
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Get session data

```
$remember = $this->session->userdata('remember');
```

You can reference [[here]](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)